# Как при наведении на картинку менять цвет остальных картинок Grid сетки?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Столкнулся с такой ситуацией - нужно при наведении на картинку поменять цвет другим. С js не дружу, поэтому буду рад хотя бы минимальным пояснениям. Спасибо (просьба показать как изменить освещенность изображений, а не цвет заливки блока)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.catalog__title{
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #000;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.catalog-item {
    padding: 5px;
 }
  
.color {
  background:black;
  height: 40px;
  width:40px;
}

.catalog-grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
```

```html
<div class="catalog__inner">
  <div class="catalog__title">Каталог</div>
  <div class="catalog-grid">
    <div class="catalog-item"><div class="color"></div></div>
    <div class="catalog-item"><div class="color"></div></div>
    <div class="catalog-item"><div class="color"></div></div>
    <div class="catalog-item"><div class="color"></div></div>
    <div class="catalog-item"><div class="color"></div></div>
    <div class="catalog-item"><div class="color"></div></div>
    <div class="catalog-item"><div class="color"></div></div>
    <div class="catalog-item"><div class="color"></div></div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не вижу смысла использовать JS для декоративных целей. CSS здесь вполне справляется. Используйте для затемнения `filter: brightness(50%)` :

```css
.catalog__title {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #000;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.catalog-item {
  padding: 5px;
}

.color {
  background: purple;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.catalog-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.catalog-grid:hover .color:not(:hover) {
  filter: brightness(50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="catalog__inner">
  <div class="catalog__title">Каталог</div>
  <div class="catalog-grid">
    <div class="catalog-item"><div class="color"></div></div>
    <div class="catalog-item"><div class="color"></div></div>
    <div class="catalog-item"><div class="color"></div></div>
    <div class="catalog-item"><div class="color"></div></div>
    <div class="catalog-item"><div class="color"></div></div>
    <div class="catalog-item"><div class="color"></div></div>
    <div class="catalog-item"><div class="color"></div></div>
    <div class="catalog-item"><div class="color"></div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. А насчёт второй части вопроса, с затемнением всех элементов, кроме того, на который наведен курсор?

Comment: @DzenisenkaFiodar, Вы пример запускали?

Comment: @DzenisenkaFiodar, жмете "Показать код", затем "Выполнить код", смотрите и тестируете результат.